# Display attribute even when object is null in Serialization

Tags: c#, xml

```
    public class CustomPropertiesItem
    {
       [XmlAttribute("customPropertiesKey")]
       public string Key { get; set; }

       [XmlText]
       public string Value { get; set; }

    }
```

Above is the class I have to use in my XmlWriter serialization.

It works, well kind off.... currently when my CustomPropertiesItem object is not null, you see it display the attribute but when CustomPropertiesItem object is null it doesn' display the attributes.  Both of these attributes should always be there.

```
<customPropertiesItem customPropertiesKey="attribute1" /> 
<customPropertiesItem xsi:nil="true" />
```

I want it to serialize into

```
  <customPropertiesItem customPropertiesKey="attribute1" /> 
  <customPropertiesItem customPropertiesKey="attribute2" />
```

Is there a way I can do this by changing my class?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do; you have a `null` valued `CustomPropertiesItem` reference, and you want to serialize the value of it's `CustomPropertiesItem.Key`?  You can't - the class itself is null.  If this is not what you're trying to do, can you make a [simple but complete c# example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that creates the bad XML?

Comment: You're right, I think what i have is correct and what I'm trying to do is wrong... this occurred because someone pointed out a possible bug and I thought it maybe my fault...but the real issue is they are sending me a null object to begin with.